# Modifying non-const char array that is referred to by const char array

Tags: c, constants

Consider the following code:

```
struct ns_test{
    char *str;
};

struct ns_test *ns_test_alloc(char *str){
    struct ns_test *nt = malloc(sizeof(*nt));
    nt->str = str;
    return nt;
}

const char *ns_test_get_str(struct ns_test *tst){
    return tst->str;
}

void ns_test_release(struct ns_test* tst){
    free(tst);
}

void ns_test_set_char(struct ns_test *tst, size_t i, char c){
    tst->str[i] = c;
}

int main(void){
    char arr[] = "1234567890";
    struct ns_test *ns_test_ptr = ns_test_alloc(arr);
    const char *str = ns_test_get_str(ns_test_ptr);
    printf("%s\n", str); //1234567890
    ns_test_set_char(ns_test_ptr, 4, 'a');
    printf("%s\n", str); //1234a67890
}
```

***The question is***: Is the behavior of the code undefined?

I think it is.

The Standard specifies at `6.7.3(p6)`:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
>   const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified
>   type, the behavior is undefined.

So to avoid this sort of UB we need `const char *ns_test_get_str(struct ns_test *tst)` to copy the `char *str` instead. But the main point was to avoid the copying and restrict the modification to the only `void ns_test_set_char(struct ns_test *tst, size_t i, char c)` which may do some sanity checks or something else prior.

Comment: But the malloced array never was const. Only the pointer had this type . There is no UB here as you derefernence another pointer.

Comment: @P__J__ but the `char arr[]` in the `main` function is not `malloc`ed.

Comment: `char arr[]` isn't really important here.  It's your `ns_test_ptr->str` that is being aliased.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons So the only thing that matters is the declared type of the object. In this case `ns_test_ptr->str` reffers to the object with declared type `char[]` as `char arr[]` was declared. So there is no problem.

Comment: As @P__J__ mentioned it meant it was always ok in case the array was malloced.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is "an object defined with a const-qualified type". What matters is how you define (IOW, "allocate memory for") the object being pointed at. If the "object" was not "created" as `const`, then it does not matter how many const or non-const pointers and references you use - you can still modify it.

So,

```
const int i = 0;
int *p = (int*)&i;
*p = 1;
```

is UB.

While

```
int i = 0;
const int *cp = &i;
int *p = (int*) cp;
*p = 1;
```

is fine.

I suspect this would even work with `new`:

```
const int *cp = new const int(0);
int *p = (int*) cp;
*p = 1;
```

is technically UB.

It does compile w/o warning on cpp.sh, but that does not mean much.

Update: as  Christian Gibbons pointed out, the language in the question is C, so the part about `new` operator does not apply. `malloc()` and friends are never `const`.

To expand this a little - one possible reason for writing the standard this way is to give the compiler freedom to use read-only memory for const values. In that case, writing to such locations becomes a crash or a noop. In other words, UB.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is a `C` question.  I understand C and C++ can treat `const` rather differently.